# "Finish" or "finished" after the "always" adverb and "every day" in the end

Tags: past-tense

The below simple test makes confuses me and the answer key for this test says the correct answer is "**finished**". Why "**finish**" is not the correct one? The first part of the sentence refers to the past time, but when I see the "**always**" adverb that mentions the action happens repeatedly (finished his work) and also "**every day**" comes at the end of the sentence; I guess "***finish***" is the best choice, and maybe the answer key mistakes, unsure about it and I wonder to learn about this simple grammar that I don't know!

Is it usual to use the past form of a verb after "**always**" while "**every day**" comes at the end?

> You could tell the time by him because he always ....... work at exactly the same time every day.
>
> (a) **ends**
> (b) **ended**
> (c) **finish**
> (d) **finished**

Comment: The modal auxiliary verb "could" is past tense meaning that the whole sentence refers to past time. The preterite lexical verb "finished" is thus correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause needs to have a conjugated verb, so the answer could only be "he **finishes**" or "he **finished**".  "He finish" is not correctly conjugated.

Only **finished** is in the answer key, so it must be the right one!

But let's look at why "he **finishes**" is not correct.  The first part of the sentence (*You could tell...*) tells us that this is something that happened in the past.  This alone should suggest that the second part of the sentence should be in the past tense too.

What about the word *always*?  The word *always* actually does not make a difference here: you can refer to something that always happened in the past.  Saying "he finishes at exactly the same time" would mean that he still does it.  Maybe he still does, but that doesn't matter; what matters is that he *did* in the past, at the time that you *could tell*.

Comment: Helpful description @stangdon, thanks.